# Third level domains

Tags: bind, domain, url

I have a linux computer accessible from the internet and I have registered a free dynamic DNS service, let's say its address on the internet is xx.yy.com.

On this computer I have two processes listening: tomcat on port 80 and a small program written by myself on 8080.

As expected I can reach these two respectively with the URLs "xx.yy.com" and "xx.yy.com:8080".
I would like to set up a third-level domain to bind to the 8080 port, so that when I type (e.g.) "aa.xx.yy.com" on a browser it has the same effects of "xx.yy.com:8080".

I have no clue on how to do that, can it be done via tomcat configuration (I would rather it be a system configuration than having to rely on tomcat)?

Do I have to set up some daemon to do it for me (I have read about bind)?

Can it be done so that the port 8080 is hidden? I have realized that my work network blocks outgoing connections on ports that are not 80 or 443. So I figured out that a good solution to that may be to move tomcat on another port and put something on 80 to internally redirect  traffic to the correct socket. Can it be done? How? Any guide around?

Thank you

Comment: Your DDNS service is allowing you to create "aa.xx.yy.com", correct?

Comment: I should check again but I remember it didn't allow me to specify a port. What if I set my own DNS? Will my definitions be exported to other DNS servers?

Comment: Where ports are concerned, your DDNS service doesn't care, and doesn't even have the capabilities to interfere with the ports you're using. Everything related to which ports you have services listening on is done on your server. As far as the DNS records for your subdomain, if you want it to be a publicly accessible subdomain, I think you'll need to set it up through your DDNS service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into SRV Records, but your question is fundamentally missing what DNS actually does.

Notwithstanding the aforementioned SRV Recrod, all DNS does is translate a name (e. g. host.example.com) to an IP address (169.254.1.2); nothing more.  It's a "network phone book".  It doesn't know or care about individual ports on a host which is assigned to an IP address.

That said, there are ways to do what you ask:

- Apache `VirtualHost`s which proxy to the desired location
- Web pages that set up a full-window `IFRAME` which loads the desired location in a frams
- `iptables` or other firewall shenannigans

Comment: I see, I thought the DNS just translated the "example.com" part, and then the server on "example.com" redirected to "host".

The iptables way of doing it interests me, any more detail on that?

Comment: You can tell `iptables` to listen for an inbound connection on port 80, and forward it to an internal IP address or loopback address on port 8080.  I don't have the exact incantation for this off the top of my head, as I usually use `VirtualHosts` for this sort of thing, and the Shoreline Firewall to handle `iptables` for me, as I'm lazy. (:

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieve using Apache `ProxyPass` module

This Steps for Ubuntu Server

**Step 1# Install ProxyPass module**

- `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html libxml2-dev`

**Step 2# Enable module**

- `a2enmod proxypass`
- `a2enmod proxy`

**Step 3# Define following directives in Respective Virtual Container**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost aa.xx.yy.com:80>
     ServerAdmin support@aa.xx.yy.com
     ServerName aa.xx.yy.com

     ProxyRequests On
     ProxyPass /   http://xx.yy.com:8080
     ProxyPassReverse /   http://xx.yy.com:8080

     # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
     #SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 4# reload apache**

- `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Now test your URL and check error logs if there is any issue while loading web page